# How to modify map lookup in log4j

Tags: java, xml, logging, properties, log4j

I need to define some properties in map Lookup in log4j; 
so is there any way I can modify and add some properties in the Map Lookup ??
Any guide or suggestion would be appreciable
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
MainMapLookup.setMainArguments("key","value");
```

and get value from xml :

```
${main:key}
```